# Sublime Text 'find in files' gives <binary> in the find results

Tags: search, find, full-text-search, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

HotKey: Shift+Ctrl+F

Correct result:
[image]Error results,

you can find  the results just show as `'<binary>'`.I've searched this problem in google,but get nothing,

[image: Error results]

Here is **[log text](https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-ap-northeast-1-830616569724/stackshare/main_log.zip).**
Thanks for anyone give suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file most likely contains non UTF-8 encoded characters, binary characters or the content encoding cannot be guessed. Thus, it is not reliable to show search result summary.

Comment: I copy the text and save as utf-8,still show <binary>.If I copy the part of text,then search,the results shows correct.full text nearlly about 8M,if it's results too big to show ?

Comment: Hmm. That could be one reason - sounds like a cheap workaround instead of putting "This file is too big to show search result summary". Or the other reason is that there is a bad character somewhere in the text stream, making it appear as binary.

Answer (score 3):

need convert control characters

```
java -jar replacecontrol.jar *filepath*
```

[replacecontrol.jar](https://github.com/jw1415/myFile/blob/master/replacecontrol.jar)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly this tool does to exactly what control characters? It would also be helpful to open-source it so we can read it. Even the readme in your repo doesn't say anything about what this does or how or why.

Comment: this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

From Sublimetext Forum

**In general, if a file contains any ASCII characters < 32,
except 0x3, 0x9, 0xa, 0xc or 0xd, then it’s considered binary**

Reading that I searched [\x00-\x09] and found a \x02
Then deleted that character; Problem disappeared

Next step would have been [\x0B-\x1F]  as x0A is newline
But I did not need it

Answer (score 0):

u can use regexp `[^[:print:]\t\r\n]` to replace all text, then u can find your result without binary.